# How to type a method to return Primitive or Instance of passed Class?

Tags: typescript

I have a generic class with a method that should return either primitives (in case a parameter is a wrapper object to a primitive type (e.g. Number)) or an instance of the constructor passed.

Thats what I tried:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-types */
type returnPrimitive<T extends any> = T extends String ? string
  : T extends Number ? number
  : T extends Boolean ? boolean
  : T
/* eslint-enable */

type ctor<T = any> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T & { valueOf(): returnPrimitive<T>}
  [s: string]: any
}


class Foo<T> {
  Type: ctor<T>
  constructor (Type: ctor<T>) {
    this.Type = Type
  }

  getValue(val: any): returnPrimitive<T> {
    const a = new this.Type(val)
    // cast to primitive or return a
  }
}
```

However, it does not really work as expected. I want it to pick up the type automatically through the type parameter in the constructor. That works well when I pass in Number or other primitive wrapper but wants to return the constructor instead of an instance for any other Class I pass in.

```js
class Matrix{}
new Foo(Number).getValue() // correctly returns number
new Foo(Matrix).getValue() // returns typeof Matrix instead of Matrix
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which version of TS compiler do you use?

Comment: Installed is 4.0.5 but there is no problem installing updates

Comment: What type do you want to return when you pass in ```Matrix``` for example? Class type or instance type?

Comment: Instance of matrix

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why do you need this?

Comment: Because that's how I designed it. It shouldn't matter why I need this tho... If it is not possible then this is a legit answer but I feel like it should be possible

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, [see here](https://tsplay.dev/RwRgYN).  The fact that your example code seems to have a `const` in the class definition makes me think you might have put the code in here without testing it.  Could you try to make sure your code constitutes a [mcve] so someone can help you?  Or maybe the problem has been solved by itself and we should close the question?  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz you are right, it seems like there is no issue. Its doing what it should. Wonder why it doesn't work with my setup then...